# Mvc RedirectToAction Is Not Open New .cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I want to be open new .cshtml using RedirectToAction. But is not working. Depot ActionFilter is opening. But url doesn't change. Help me please.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string storageid)
{

    return RedirectToAction("Depot",new RouteValueDictionary(new { Controller = "Depot", Action = "Depot", storageId = storageid }));
}


public ActionResult Depot(string storageid)
{

    return View("Depot");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your route definitions, I'd just use:

```
return RedirectToAction("Depot", "Depot", new { storageid = storageid });
```

which is more straightforward and less error prone.

Note: `storageid` is used in the above, not `storageId` (note the capital I in Id) as defined in your `RouteValueDictionary` - it should be `storageid` according to your parameter definition in `ActionResult Depot`